# Remove server from react-boilerplate

Tags: react-boilerplate

How should one do to remove server folder from react-boilerplate? Question is also asked here by another person https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/2110.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the server?

Comment: @DineshPandiyan I use koa instead of express.

Comment: react-boilerplate is heavily integrated with hot reload middleware in express. You're most likely better off setting things up fresh with a new create-react-app eject.

Comment: @DineshPandiyan Ok... Well I fixed it on my own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove with `rm -rf ./server` if you feel harassed :)

Comment: Raguzzini Haha ok.. But how to adjust webpack to not use the server folder?

Comment: The only refs in webpack are about logger in development webpack config, remove them and that's it :)

Comment: Raguzzina where do you mean? Cant find anything about logger in `https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js`

Comment: I was looking for it in a older version of boilerplate. In the new one webpack does not make use at all of /server scripts

Comment: Ah ok! Do you use react-boilerplate as well?

Comment: I used it for a couple of projects but saga is an overkill for the most of the projects I work on so I've ended up using my own boilerplate

Comment: Ok :) I found saga to be excellent and clean solution. Anyway, I accept your answer because it is funny :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182862/discussion-between-mose-raguzzini-and-user1665355).

Answer (score 1):

Removing just server folder will not work because the webpack dev configuration is utilising it for hot reload as well as your `npm start` command starts express server from this folder.

**If you want to remove server folder completely and still want the application to be working as it was like hot reloading etc, follow the below steps. We will require webpack dev server in that case:**

- Remove `./server` folder manually.
- Install `webpack-dev-server` and `react-hot-loader` as dev dependencies.
- In  your `./internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js`, do the following modifications:

  - Change entry to this:

    ```
    entry: [
          require.resolve('react-app-polyfill/ie11'),
          'react-hot-loader/patch',
          `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000/`,
          'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js'), // Start with js/app.js
    ],
    ```
  - Add publicPath in output:

    ```
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
        publicPath: `http://localhost:3000/`,
    },
    ```
  - Add webpack dev server config property in the same file:

    ```
    devServer: {
       port: 3000,
       publicPath: `http://localhost:3000/`,
       compress: true,
       noInfo: false,
       stats: 'errors-only',
       inline: true,
       lazy: false,
       hot: true,
       open: true,
       overlay: true,
       headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
       contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app', 'build'),
       watchOptions: {
           aggregateTimeout: 300,
           ignored: /node_modules/,
           poll: 100,
       },
       historyApiFallback: {
           verbose: true,
           disableDotRule: false,
       },
    },
    ```
  - In `./internals/webpack/webpack.base.babel.js`, add the line:

    ```
    devServer: options.devServer,
    ```

And finally, modify your start script in `package.json` as below:

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node --trace-warnings ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --color --config internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js",
```

And you are good to go!!